# Script for adding a text in the ClipBoard when a User copy some text from my webpage

Tags: jquery, html, javascript

I use Asp.net and C# 4, but I suppose for this question I need some JavaScript (maybe jquery).

I have a Web Page, when a User copy some text from the page, I would like that in his Clipboards will be added some custom Text, for example the source URL where he copied the source text from.
In this way when he PAST the text he can see the original Text + The custom Text added.

An example of implementation you can find here. Simple Copy and Pase from this page to a Text File and you can see what I need.

http://www.miamiherald.com/2011/10/03/2437413/asian-markets-lower-on-greek-debt.html

Any idea how to do it? Any reference? Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Interesting.. since JavaScript has no direct clipboard access and it does not use Flash it apparently uses some technique to affect what is copied by the browser.

Comment: yes it is a pretty interesting, what bout some jquery plugins? Unfortunately I cannot figure out how they did it.

Comment: I found an hosted solution http://www.tynt.com/ interesting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for the oncopy event.  [An simple example of it's usage](http://help.dottoro.com/ljwexqxl.php)

[Another example, adding a copyright warning](http://bavotasan.com/2010/add-a-copyright-notice-to-copied-text/)